# filesystems "remove_all" vulnerability is not defined error

Tags: c++, filesystems, visual-studio-2019, console-application

Hello i started c++ and im using Visual Studio 2017 and i want deletin all files/folder inside a folder and i tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    remove_all("C:\myfolder");
    printf("All items deleted!");

    return 0;
}
```

`remove();` is works for me but `remove_all();` doesn't work even i use `#include <filesystem>`

This is what i what i get while im using `remove_all();`:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Hide Status Error (active)
> E0020 "remove_all" vulnerability is not defined.

is it possible to fix? or there another method to delete all files inside a folder?

Not: My VisualStudio is so laggy and sometimes it stay displays error even i fix it. Thanks

My c++ version:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwNKU.png)

Comment: From what I can see, you are not using `std::filesystem::remove_all`, you need `filesystem::remove_all` (since you've done `using namespace std;`. Also `\m` is an invalid escape sequence. You probably wanted `\\m`

Comment: Helo i tried it like: `std::filesystem::remove_all("C:\myfolder");` but now im taking this error: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Hide Status
Error (active) E0276 Name after '::' must be class or namespace".

Comment: I don't know where that comes from but `\m` is still invalid. And, since you use `printf` you should also `#include <cstdio>`

Comment: are you meaning \m by `("C:\myfolder");`?  i  changed it like `("C:\\myfolder");`

Comment: Yes, exactly, or use `"C:/myfolder"`

Comment: okay secondly i tried this: `filesystem::remove_all("C:\\myfolder");` and im getting this error: 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Hide Status
Error (active) E0276 Name after '::' must be class or namespace

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you are using C++17 or later? Have you set it to C++17 or later explicitly? Visual Studio defaults to C++14.

Comment: Hello i edited and added a photo about my c++ version is it correct? or how i can install latest c++? sorry im a noob :)

Comment: That's not the version of the C++ standard you are using. That's the version of the redistributable libraries. Go in to the project/properties and check what the `C++ Language Standard` setting says. Change it to C++17 or later.

Comment: it says Default (ISO C++14 Standart) so how i can upgrade it to c++ 17 any link?

Comment: Just change it in the menu you have there. Click on the little downarrow to the right and a dropdown list should appear.

Comment: Lovely! :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the snippet: added `filesystem::` and `\\`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    filesystem::remove_all("XX:\\XX\\TestFolder");
    printf("All items deleted!");

    return 0;
}
```

And  use the C++ 17 in Project's properties.(Right click the project and you will see the `properties` page on the last line )
[image]

Comment: Hello it worked but i need delete all files inside any folder not folder for example: i want delete all files inside temp not temp folder. Thanks <3

Comment: Remove_all will delete all files, a little trick is that you can create a new folder in that directory.  `#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<fileapi.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "E:\\VS\\TestFolder";
    filesystem::remove_all(path);
    CreateDirectoryA(path.c_str(), NULL);
    printf("All items deleted!");
    return 0;
} `